# Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to http://test6/:80 (Unable to find the socket transport "http"

Tags: php, sockets

I try to use code below on my local server

```
<?php
$hostname = "http://test6/";
$path = "/test6/handler.php";
$line = "";

$fp = fsockopen($hostname, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) echo "$errstr ($errno) <br />\n";
else 
{
    $data = "name=".urlencode("TestName")."&pass=".urlencode("TestPassword")."\r\n\r\n";
    $headers = "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Host: $hostname\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; ; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $headers.$data);

    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $line .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

echo $line;
?>
```

but as result I got

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to http ://test6/:80 (Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\Winginx\home\test6\public_html\index.php on line 6 Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (11477112)

`extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini` is enabled.

Can someone explain me how to make it work?

Comment: Remove `http://` and the trailing slash. I should just be `test6`. You want a host name, not protocol information.

Comment: You've also got one too many `\r\n` before the POST data